# Matrix-vector product inequality

Tags: matrices

Let be $A$ a nonnegative matrix. Is it true that if $A^mx>K$ (i.e. all its components are strictly greater then $K$) then $Ax>h$ where $h$ doesn't depend on $x$ but eventually only on $A, m$ and $K$?